# directive dynamic templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

To display many popin using angular i have used in my home page

**template1.html** will be displayed as popin

worked if i fix the .html to displayed .

```
  <a class="vsn_alert-item-link" tooltip-special="template1.html" tooltip-placement="right">
```

in .js side there is my directive

```
 .directive('tooltipSpecial', ['$uibTooltip', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 
      function($uibTooltip, $rootScope, $timeout) {
         return $uibTooltip('tooltipSpecial', 'tooltip', 'click');
 }]);'
```

the directive is :

```
.directive( 'tooltipSpecialPopup', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  var templateUrl="";
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },

    controller: function($rootScope, $scope){
     $scope.$apply();
    } ,
      templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.content
       }
  };
```

}])

the result is this error :

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: {{content}} (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$compile/tpload?p0=%7B%7Bcontent%7D%7D&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.js:68
    at handleError (angular.js:18978)
    at processQueue (angular.js:15961)
    at angular.js:15977
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17045)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17337)
    at done (angular.js:11572)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11778)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11711)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('hymn', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           // some ode
       },
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.templateUrl || 'some/path/default.html'
       }
   }
});
```

So you can provide templateUrl via markup

```
<hymn template-url="contentUrl"><hymn>
```

Now you just take a care that property contentUrl populates with dynamically generated path.

Comment: templateurl containe the second value all times